# postgresql accidentalor implicit view creation when creating self joined query

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a daily query of our EMR (Electronic medical records) database.  Vendor of the EMR says that the query is creating "views" on the database.  these views are interfering with a table update routine that runs when we install patches.  i have no view commands in the query.

Am I creating an implicit view of somekind with the following query

```
SELECT 
"Scheduled"."foo1",
"Scheduled"."foo2",
"Scheduled"."foo3",
FROM
(SELECT
"public".profile.prof_c_foop1 AS "foo1",
"public".profile.prof_c_foop2 AS "foo2",
"public".profile.prof_c_foop3 AS "foo3",

FROM
"public".scheduling_event
JOIN "public".scheduling_appointment ON "public".scheduling_appointment.sch5appt_eventid = "public".scheduling_event.sch5event_id
JOIN "public".profile ON "public".scheduling_event.sch5event_profile = "public".profile.prof_c_profilenum
JOIN "public".scheduling_appointment_resource ON "public".scheduling_appointment_resource.sch5apptres_apptid = "public".scheduling_appointment.sch5appt_id
JOIN "public".scheduling_resource ON "public".scheduling_appointment_resource.sch5apptres_resid = "public".scheduling_resource.sch5res_id
JOIN "public".scheduling_location ON "public".scheduling_location.sch5loc_id = "public".scheduling_resource.sch5res_id
JOIN "public".scheduling_event_task ON "public".scheduling_event_task.sch5evtks_event_id = "public".scheduling_event.sch5event_id
JOIN "public".scheduling_task ON "public".scheduling_event_task.sch5evtks_task_id = "public".scheduling_task.sch5task_id
JOIN "public".scheduling_appointment_status ON "public".scheduling_appointment_status.sch5apptstat_apptid = "public".scheduling_appointment.sch5appt_id
WHERE
"public".profile.prof_c_ip1p_phone > 0
AND
public.scheduling_appointment.sch5appt_datetime > CURRENT_DATE + interval '2 day' 
AND
public.scheduling_appointment.sch5appt_datetime < CURRENT_DATE + interval '3 days'
AND
"public".scheduling_appointment_status.sch5apptstat_code = 'S'
AND
"public".scheduling_task.sch5task_desc NOT SIMILAR TO '(SURGERY|EUFLEXXA)' ) 

   as "Scheduled"  --<<<<<<<< i think this might be where views are created maybe???<<<<<

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
"public".scheduling_appointment_status.sch5apptstat_apptid as "ApptID"
FROM
"public".scheduling_event
JOIN "public".scheduling_appointment ON "public".scheduling_appointment.sch5appt_eventid = "public".scheduling_event.sch5event_id
JOIN "public".profile ON "public".scheduling_event.sch5event_profile = "public".profile.prof_c_profilenum
JOIN "public".scheduling_appointment_resource ON "public".scheduling_appointment_resource.sch5apptres_apptid = "public".scheduling_appointment.sch5appt_id
JOIN "public".scheduling_resource ON "public".scheduling_appointment_resource.sch5apptres_resid = "public".scheduling_resource.sch5res_id
JOIN "public".scheduling_location ON "public".scheduling_location.sch5loc_id = "public".scheduling_resource.sch5res_id
JOIN "public".scheduling_event_task ON "public".scheduling_event_task.sch5evtks_event_id = "public".scheduling_event.sch5event_id
JOIN "public".scheduling_task ON "public".scheduling_event_task.sch5evtks_task_id = "public".scheduling_task.sch5task_id
JOIN "public".scheduling_appointment_status ON "public".scheduling_appointment_status.sch5apptstat_apptid = "public".scheduling_appointment.sch5appt_id
WHERE
"public".profile.prof_c_ip1p_phone > 0 --ERIC SUCKS DAN RULES
AND
public.scheduling_appointment.sch5appt_datetime > CURRENT_DATE + interval '2 day' 
AND
public.scheduling_appointment.sch5appt_datetime < CURRENT_DATE + interval '3 days'
AND
"public".scheduling_appointment_status.sch5apptstat_code = 'A' ) as "Cancelled"
ON
"Scheduled"."ApptID" = "Cancelled"."ApptID"
WHERE
"Cancelled"."ApptID" is NULL
```

Comment: discuss terminology with vendor I'd say

Comment: i am pretty sure their database backend is pretty much trash.  There table systems alone are just ridiculous. I just wanted to make sure i wasn't doing something that was really well known, but I just didn't know about.  thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't tell from query. Eg:

create empty table and so on to imply implicit view creation:

```
t=# create table tt(i int);
CREATE TABLE

t=# create function trick() returns table (i int) as
$$begin
create view vv as select 1;
return query select * from vv;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS
t-#     ON SELECT TO tt
t-#     DO INSTEAD
t-#         SELECT * FROM trick();
CREATE RULE
```

now the view does not exist:

```
t=# select * from vv;
ERROR:  relation "vv" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from vv;
                      ^
```

you run your select on existing empty table:

```
t=# select * from tt;
 i
---
 1
(1 row)
```

and the view was created:

```
t=# select * from vv;
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

Talk to your vendor if you want to know what view was created (if any) or dig the structure - query is not enough to tell

Comment: so i got a response back from the vendor.  so it was what we supposed.  poor database management on their end.  however they had their settings, it basically was leaving a connection open to each table queried. they were calling these connections "views" due to their originally being a cobol shop.  these "views" interferred with their update program when they patched.